# Can I run git shell and execute command from cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, git-shell

I would like to write a bat script that runs simultaneously Unity, visual studio and git shell. I would like to make git shell change directory (it always start at default github's repositories location), but I can't figure how.

so far, I've got something like that:

```
echo off

d:
cd D:\<path>\Visual Studio\Common7\IDE
start .\devenv.exe "C:\<path>\solution.sln"

cd D:\<path>\Unity\Editor
start .\Unity.exe -projectPath "C:\<path>\project directory"

c:
cd C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\GitHub\
start .\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell //and now i need to execute "cd ../my project" on it
```